# Implementing access control/authorization for UI Widgets in Web Applications

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security, kendo-ui

I'm looking into various ways of doing dynamic access control in my web application. Here is my  scenario:

> My web page has a Grid Widget (Kendo UI Grid) with row level edit
>   operations. Based on a user's entitlement, I would like to
>   enable/disable the edit functionality on the Grid. I can implement the access control list in LDAP or implement my own entitlement structure in a database. I use Spring MVC & Kendo UI and I'm in the process of considering AngularJS along with Kendo UI to build my web app.

One possible approach might be to use Spring security to integrate with the entitlements back end and use the Spring Security tag libs to implement the access control in the jsp. But, I'm not sure if this is the best approach. I'm not yet sufficiently familiar with AngularJS to determine if AngularJS can help me with this kind of authorization for UI widgets.

Your suggestions and experiences with various frameworks in implementing this kind of access control would be very helpful.

Comment: Angular can not verify and authenticate a request, that is something the server has to do so whether jquery, angular, ember, the web service layer will have to validate that each request is valid.  That being said, you can maintain your user state inside an angular app quite easily.

Comment: @lucuma I understand that angular cannot authenticate the request, but is there way for me to pass authorization information to angular and then use that to determine if the UI widget should be displayed or not?

Comment: Absolutely and is rather common to share user state across an entire application including UI Widgets which are called `directives` in the Angular world.